# Reproducing results from previous answer is not working due to using new version of lme4

Tags: r, lme4

I have tried to reproduce the results from the answers for this question “Estimating random effects and applying user defined correlation/covariance structure with R lme4 or nlme package “ https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18563/estimating-random-effects-and-applying-user-defined-correlation-covariance-struc

Aaron Rendahl's codes

```
 library(pedigreemm)
 relmatmm <- function (formula, data, family = NULL, REML = TRUE, relmat = list(), 
control = list(), start = NULL, verbose = FALSE, subset, 
weights, na.action, offset, contrasts = NULL, model = TRUE, 
x = TRUE, ...) 
{
mc <- match.call()
lmerc <- mc
lmerc[[1]] <- as.name("lmer")
lmerc$relmat <- NULL
if (!length(relmat)) 
    return(eval.parent(lmerc))
stopifnot(is.list(relmat), length(names(relmat)) == length(relmat))
lmerc$doFit <- FALSE
lmf <- eval(lmerc, parent.frame())
relfac <- relmat
relnms <- names(relmat)
stopifnot(all(relnms %in% names(lmf$FL$fl)))
asgn <- attr(lmf$FL$fl, "assign")
for (i in seq_along(relmat)) {
    tn <- which(match(relnms[i], names(lmf$FL$fl)) == asgn)
    if (length(tn) > 1) 
        stop("a relationship matrix must be associated with only one random effects term")
    Zt <- lmf$FL$trms[[tn]]$Zt
    relmat[[i]] <- Matrix(relmat[[i]][rownames(Zt), rownames(Zt)], 
        sparse = TRUE)
    relfac[[i]] <- chol(relmat[[i]])
    lmf$FL$trms[[tn]]$Zt <- lmf$FL$trms[[tn]]$A <- relfac[[i]] %*% Zt
}
ans <- do.call(if (!is.null(lmf$glmFit)) 
    lme4:::glmer_finalize
else lme4:::lmer_finalize, lmf)
ans <- new("pedigreemm", relfac = relfac, ans)
ans@call <- match.call()
ans
}
```

### the original example

```
 set.seed(1234)
 mydata <- data.frame (gen = factor(rep(1:10, each = 10)),
                  repl = factor(rep(1:10, 10)),
                  yld = rnorm(10, 5, 0.5))
library(lme4)
covmat <- round(nearPD(matrix(runif(100, 0, 0.2), nrow = 10))$mat, 2)
diag(covmat) <- diag(covmat)/10+1
rownames(covmat) <- colnames(covmat) <- levels(mydata$gen)
m <- relmatmm(yld ~ (1|gen) + (1|repl), relmat=list(gen=covmat), data=mydata)
```

### here is the error message

```
Error in lmf$FL : $ operator not defined for this S4 class
In addition: Warning message:
In checkArgs("lmer", doFit = FALSE) : extra argument(s) ‘doFit’ disregarded
```

I will appreciate any help ?
Thanks

Comment: this is using internal structures from `lme4` that have changed in the new version of `lme4`.  I don't have time to look this over right now: you may need to ask the original author (Aaron Rendahl?) to update the code to work with the new version of `lme4` (see `help("modular",package="lme4")` for a start.  It might also be helpful to contact the maintainer of the `pedigreemm` package to see if they can help.

Comment: PS this should actually be easier to do with the new version of `lme4` than it was before due to the improved modularity (see previous comment), but it still means the code needs to be redone ...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104475/how-to-modify-slots-lme4-1-0/19106863#19106863

Answer (score 2):

This is a re-implementation of the previous code -- I have done some slight modifications, and I **have not tested it in any way** -- test yourself and/or use at your own risk.

First create a slightly more modularized function that constructs the deviance function and fits the model:

```
doFit <- function(lmod,lmm=TRUE) {
    ## see ?modular
    if (lmm) {
        devfun <- do.call(mkLmerDevfun, lmod)
        opt <- optimizeLmer(devfun)
        mkMerMod(environment(devfun), opt, lmod$reTrms, fr = lmod$fr)
    } else {
        devfun <- do.call(mkGlmerDevfun, lmod)
        opt <- optimizeGlmer(devfun)
        devfun <- updateGlmerDevfun(devfun, lmod$reTrms)
        opt <- optimizeGlmer(devfun, stage=2)
        mkMerMod(environment(devfun), opt, lmod$reTrms, fr = lmod$fr)
    }
}
```

Now create a function to construct the object that `doFit` needs and modify it:

```
relmatmm <- function (formula, ..., lmm=TRUE, relmat = list()) {
    ff <- if (lmm) lFormula(formula, ...) else glFormula(formula, ...)
    stopifnot(is.list(relmat), length(names(relmat)) == length(relmat))
    relnms <- names(relmat)
    relfac <- relmat
    flist <- ff$reTrms[["flist"]]   ## list of factors
     ## random-effects design matrix components
    Ztlist <- ff$reTrms[["Ztlist"]]
    stopifnot(all(relnms %in% names(flist)))
    asgn <- attr(flist, "assign")
    for (i in seq_along(relmat)) {
        tn <- which(match(relnms[i], names(flist)) == asgn)
        if (length(tn) > 1) 
            stop("a relationship matrix must be",
                 " associated with only one random effects term")
        zn <- rownames(Ztlist[[i]])
        relmat[[i]] <- Matrix(relmat[[i]][zn,zn],sparse = TRUE)
        relfac[[i]] <- chol(relmat[[i]])
        Ztlist[[i]] <-  relfac[[i]] %*% Ztlist[[i]]
    }
    ff$reTrms[["Ztlist"]] <- Ztlist
    ff$reTrms[["Zt"]] <- do.call(rBind,Ztlist)
    fit <- doFit(ff,lmm)
}
```

Example

```
set.seed(1234)
mydata <- data.frame (gen = factor(rep(1:10, each = 10)),
                  repl = factor(rep(1:10, 10)),
                  yld = rnorm(10, 5, 0.5))

library(lme4)
covmat <- round(nearPD(matrix(runif(100, 0, 0.2), nrow = 10))$mat, 2)
diag(covmat) <- diag(covmat)/10+1
rownames(covmat) <- colnames(covmat) <- levels(mydata$gen)

m <- relmatmm(yld ~ (1|gen) + (1|repl), relmat=list(gen=covmat), 
     data=mydata)
```

This runs -- I don't know if the output is correct.  It also doesn't make the resulting object into a `pedigreemm` object ...

Comment: Dear Ben: thank you so much for the reimplementing Aaron codes --- i have tried to post this comment long ago but i was not allowed to do so--- when applied your new codes i got this error: Error in relmat[[i]][zn, zn] : 
  invalid or not-yet-implemented 'Matrix' subsetting

Comment: works for me.  Can you post results of `sessionInfo()` (specifically, versions of `Matrix` and `lme4`) ?

Comment: here is my sessionInfo()
         R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)
         Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
         [1] pedigreemm_0.3-1 ------ [22] lme4_1.0-4 ----  Matrix_1.0-12

Comment: Are you willing to try updating `Matrix`, `RcppEigen`, and `lme4` (in that order) to versions 1.1-0, 0.3.2.0, and 1.0-5 respectively ... ?  (Updating Matrix is the important part, but if you don't then update (or at least re-install) `RcppEigen` and `lme4`, you'll run into trouble

Comment: i will try updating all of them as you recommended

Comment: Ben: i reinstalled R it self + the packages that you recommended and here is what i got: > m <- relmatmm(yld ~ (1|gen) + (1|repl), relmat=list(gen=covmat), 
+      data=mydata)
Error in relmat[[i]][zn, zn] : 
  invalid or not-yet-implemented 'Matrix' subsetting
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
[1] pedigreemm_0.3-1 lme4_1.0-5   Matrix_1.1-0